# Able to keep reference to thread in which Timer is created?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, timer

My current project makes use of 8-10 timers, depending on the user's preferences. At the end of each user session, I would like to invalidate all of the timers so that they are properly reset for future sessions.

Presently, I am having issues in which all of the timers are not invalidated at the end of user session, despite calling `.invalidate()` on all timers, which are stored as properties to the view controller.

I looked into this, Apple documentation on `invalidate` notes that it [must be called in the same thread](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer/1415405-invalidate?language=objc) that the Timer was created. I would prefer not to specify the thread in which the timers are called, but rather was wondering if it is possible to **keep references to the threads** in which the timers are called, and then individually go to the threads to invalidate them?

Thanks.

Current code in my `invalidateTimers` function, called at the end of each user session.

```
private func invalidateTimers() {
    self.masterTimer?.invalidate()
    self.fadeOutTimer?.invalidate()
    self.fadeInTimer?.invalidate()
    self.volumeAdjustmentTimer?.invalidate()
    self.maintainAppRemoteTimer?.invalidate()
    self.mintesBeforeStartTimer?.invalidate()
    self.safetyFadeAudioTimer?.invalidate()
    self.safetyFadeVideoTimer?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: The simplest way is to create and invalidate your timers from the main queue. That way you know that it will be running on the main thread.

Comment: Why do the timers need to be on separate threads?

Comment: Regarding not starting and invalidating the timers on the main thread, my hypothesis was that it may create some undesired consequences or putting too much work on the main thread. If this concern is overblown, I am also keen to move everything to the main thread.

Comment: You won't have too much overhead with the timers on the main thread. If your timers' tasks are indeed too heavy, you can move the processing on separate threads when your timer fires.